# Godot Android App: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException during Play Store Pre-testing

Tags: godot, android-multidex

I have recently developed an Android application using Godot, and after successful testing on both virtual and real devices, I exported the AAB file and uploaded it to the Google Play Store. However, during the pre-testing phase, I encountered an unexpected exception that is preventing the app from running correctly.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "False" on path: DexPathList[[zip file 
"/data/app/~~AxhHqfTD_ygPLu14e2LeCQ==/org.game-Qv9tOyuiAc-lgxdpUTQOWQ==/base.apk", zip file 
"/data/app/~~AxhHqfTD_ygPLu14e2LeCQ==/org.game-Qv9tOyuiAc-lgxdpUTQOWQ==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk", 
zip file "/data/app/~~AxhHqfTD_ygPLu14e2LeCQ==/org.game-Qv9tOyuiAc-
lgxdpUTQOWQ==/split_config.en.apk", zip file "/data/app/~~AxhHqfTD_ygPLu14e2LeCQ==/org.game-
Qv9tOyuiAc-lgxdpUTQOWQ==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk", zip file 
"/data/app/~~AxhHqfTD_ygPLu14e2LeCQ==/org.game-Qv9tOyuiAc-
lgxdpUTQOWQ==/split_installTime.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=
[/data/app/~~AxhHqfTD_ygPLu14e2LeCQ==/org.game-Qv9tOyuiAc-lgxdpUTQOWQ==/lib/arm64, 
/data/app/~~AxhHqfTD_ygPLu14e2LeCQ==/org.game-Qv9tOyuiAc-lgxdpUTQOWQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a,
 /data/app/~~AxhHqfTD_ygPLu14e2LeCQ==/org.game-Qv9tOyuiAc-
lgxdpUTQOWQ==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, 
/data/app/~~AxhHqfTD_ygPLu14e2LeCQ==/org.game-Qv9tOyuiAc-
lgxdpUTQOWQ==/split_config.en.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/~~AxhHqfTD_ygPLu14e2LeCQ==/org.game-
Qv9tOyuiAc-lgxdpUTQOWQ==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, 
/data/app/~~AxhHqfTD_ygPLu14e2LeCQ==/org.game-Qv9tOyuiAc-
lgxdpUTQOWQ==/split_installTime.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
```

**Environment**:

- Godot Version: 3.5.2-stable
- Android Studio: android-studio-2022.2.1.20-Win
- OS: Windows

I would appreciate any insights or solutions to resolve this exception, Thank you in advance for your help!

**Troubleshooting** :
I have already tried setting `multiDexEnabled true` in the defaultConfig block of my build.gradle file, but the issue remains unresolved.

```
defaultConfig {
        // The default ignore pattern for the 'assets' directory includes hidden files and directories which are used by Godot projects.
        aaptOptions {
            ignoreAssetsPattern "!.svn:!.git:!.gitignore:!.ds_store:!*.scc:<dir>_*:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~"
        }

        ndk {
            String[] export_abi_list = getExportEnabledABIs()
            abiFilters export_abi_list
        }

        manifestPlaceholders = [godotEditorVersion: getGodotEditorVersion()]

        // Feel free to modify the application id to your own.
        applicationId getExportPackageName()
        versionCode getExportVersionCode()
        versionName getExportVersionName()
        minSdkVersion getExportMinSdkVersion()
        targetSdkVersion getExportTargetSdkVersion()
        multiDexEnabled true

        missingDimensionStrategy 'products', 'template'
//CHUNK_ANDROID_DEFAULTCONFIG_BEGIN
//CHUNK_ANDROID_DEFAULTCONFIG_END
    }
```